# Почему не удаётся отправить файл на сервер?

Tags: asp.net, сервер, post, веб-служба

Есть сервер, есть веб сервис(asp.net).
На сервере, через postman отправляю img в формате base64, он появляется в указанной папке, все нормально работает.
А вот уже извне когда отправляю тоже статус OK, upload идет, но в папке на сервере не появляется.
В чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, в чем была моя проблема, может кому пригодиться:

Когда я отправляю файл с самого сервера, файл сохранялся по указанному пути, который был указан в методе(Asp), а извне путь по умолчанию другой, наверное тот, который указан по умолчанию в вебконфиге.